# Can we still integrate systemjs in Angular 6 and lazy load module without routing

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular2-routing, lazy-loading

I am trying to lazy load module rather than adding components in entry component because i.e adding overhead to the chunk size. (Also, I don't need routing)

[Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-)

I have followed the steps mentioned by max in his article.

I came across below error
***ERROR in ./node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'***

After some research, I found that now it's the responsibility of node to provide the 'fs' module And for this, I need to add
 **"target": "node"**

in webpack.config.json. However, Angular 6 has disabled ejecting Webpack.config file anymore.
So, is the lazy loading of module still possible without routing?

Comment: Eject will be returning to Angular CLI in version 7. It was disabled temporarily while the team figured out how to implement it again since everything changed in 6.

Comment: Thanks @cgTag for information.

Comment: @cgTa Seems like angular has not enabled ng eject :(

Comment: Yeah I know. I was disappointed to see that.

Comment: This lybrary lazy load component without routing https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-lazy-load-component